# How do you put a border around a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I would like to put a border around my listview that is a few pixes wide.  I want it to to go around the entire listview piece.  How can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For this first take the LinearLayout and assign that linear layout with some color and take a list view in that linear layout. Set the `android:layout_margin="10dp"` property for list view . That means on all 4 sides 10dp space will be left. This shown as the border of the list view.

Comment: This isn't an exact answer...its just a work around.

Answer (score 92):

The other way to do it is to create a border resource that can then be reused, and it also means you won't need to create extra layout to implement it.

1. create a drawable resource

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
      <!-- use this for transparent -->
      <!-- <solid android:color="#00000000" /> -->
      <!-- use this for a background colour -->
      <solid android:color="#FFF" />
      <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#FF0000" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. then set it as the listview background

   ```
   <ListView
       android:id="@id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/border_ui" />
   ```

Comment: hi! thanks, helped me. If I put android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" in the listview, the right borderline disappears. Why is that?

Comment: @user1809923 Would need more information to tell that, probably best to create your own question! My guess is that you are declaring it match the parent width, and then pushing the right 20dp off the screen.

Comment: I have tried this solution and had the same problem with the border not showing if i have items in the lsitview. I think the problem is that the items are drawn over the background and therefor its not visible.

Comment: @JanZiesse Try removing the background from the list items and see if it then shows.

Comment: Thanks..worked for me. This should have been the selected answer.

Comment: to see the border with items in the list, I added android:padding="3sp" in the listview. granted, if your border is thicker, you may need more padding.

Answer (score 15):

Simplest way:

> ```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/listView1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"       
>     android:divider="#FFCC00"
>     android:dividerHeight="2dp"
>     android:layout_weight="1" />
> ```

Comment: This will just modify the divider of the listview's items. It will not draw a border around the whole Listview.

Comment: Works well for the `listview` divider

Answer (score 1):

### There is a much easier way to create borders and other graphic details on views.

You should use [9 Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images.They allow you to create any sort of background you like including borders. The link explains all. To verify here is an image of a [bordered list](http://tinypic.com/r/10wo0h2/8).

[Here](http://tinypic.com/r/htb2md/8) is an image of the 9 patch image I used to make that border.

Comment: While it is certainly an option, I wouldn't say it is easier, or better under most circumstances; Reason being that you need to create the 9 patches and also create for different densities. Compared to an XML file, that is far more work and a bigger APK. That said, it's very useful when you want to supply a more complex border.

Comment: It does take a little while but I really enjoy the process. Just wondering what the impact of 4, around  1-3 KB image files in the APK would be, apart from the increase in size of 4-12 KB of course.

Comment: It isn't a massive impact in size (at least in a singular context), but consistency across platforms will not be as consistent as the pixel sizes are fixed across a range of densities. The ability to tweak size or colour is far more stuffing around as well. There will possibly be a slight performance gain to using 9 patches but not enough to be noticeable in most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Though its long time the question posted, but hope it may help new comer !!!

Create **back.xml** under drawable folder of your project!!!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <!-- use this for transparent -->
    <!-- <solid android:color="#00000000" /> -->
    <!-- use this for a background colour -->
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#FFCC00" />
</shape>
```

Now set the same to your listview layout as background .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            **android:background="@drawable/back"** />
    </LinearLayout>
```

so it look like as following :

[image: listview with background border]

Here the border will around your total list view, not around each view.

TO give **separate border of your listview** do the bellow thing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the UI will appear will comes like bellow:

[image: listview with background of each view]