# How to add border to listview and different row colors at the same time

Tags: android, listview, border

I'm trying to have a border on the outside of my listview and a different color for every other row at the same time

[image]

here's the getView method from my adapter

```
        viewHolder.dateView.setText(entry.getDateString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            viewHolder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);

        }
        else{
            //viewHolder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }
```

here's the xml file which I use to make the border on the **listview** not the cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <!-- use this for transparent -->
   <!-- <solid android:color="#00000000" /> -->
   <!-- use this for a background colour -->
   <solid android:color="@color/white" />
   <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

if I set the backround to the cell it I can no longer see the border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rewrite**

You have obviously read: [How do you put a border around a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5065722/1267661) since you are using the code from the better / more popular answer. But read the bottom answer as well, I had success by adding `2dp` padding (the same width as the border.)

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_listview"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This still erases my border :/

Comment: Thanks, I managed to acheive what I wanted, I think it was what you just suggested or along the lines, I'll add my code to your post to help others in the future :)

Comment: Do you need the LinearLayout? You might be able to add the `background`, `gravity`, and `padding` attributes to the ListView and remove the LinearLayout entirely. But sometimes drawables like `background` are... finicky, so you might need it.

Comment: I can't remember exactly why I needed it, I think it was for when you select an item, it overlapped the border and looked strange.

Comment: android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp" answers the problem