# android how to set border in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my code which work fine, I just want to add border at top and bottom of `listview`. So, My question is how to add border at top and bottom of `listview`. Note: I just want to add only border and where I can place border? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listCategory"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fadeScrollbars="true"
          android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/gridlayout"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**listview_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_focussed" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed" />
</selector>
```

**listview_selector_focussed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#0a89f1" android:endColor="#56768d" android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

**listview_selector_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#0a89f1" android:endColor="#56768d" android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065722/how-do-you-put-a-border-around-a-listview

Comment: are you using custom list view ?

Comment: use header footer view for listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a header and footer, they will serve you as a border

1. In your Activity where you will declare your `ListView`;

   ```
   View v=new View(this);
   v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(<width>,>height>));
   v.setBackgroundColor(<your color>);
   ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
   list.addHeader(v);
   list.addFooter(v);
   ```
2. In your layout file at your parent layout element

   ```
   <YourParentLayoutElement
   ...
   android:paddingTop="<your_value>"
   android:paddingBottom="<your_value>"
   >
   ```