# Android : Merging two types of List with different adapters, lists get merged in UI

Tags: java, android, list

I am working on an Android project in which I have two different types of Chat possibilities. One is for `Groups` and other is for `private` or one to one communication. Now, all the Groups and Users the logged-in user can chat with is shown in `ConversationActivity`.

For this, I have  prepared two lists in the UI, and contents will be added to each list by an Async method. Each List has a separate adapter, with which I will be able to easily identify, which item was clicked.

This mechanism is working just fine, except that when the activity is opened, the list look they are layered on top of each other, obviously that is not the intention. So I indicated in the RelativeLayout, to position it above another, that also didn't help.

**How can I display two lists with two different adapters in one activity page?**

activity_conversations.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/privateRelativeLay"
        >
        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/conversationList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"

        android:id="@+id/privateRelativeLay">

        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/privateConversationList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ConversationActivity.java

```
public class ConversationActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversations);
if (isOnline()) {
            new getConversationsForLoggedInUser(this).execute();
            new getPrivateChannelsForLoggedInUser(this).execute();

        }


    public class getPrivateChannelsForLoggedInUser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResponseEntity<PrivateChannel[]>>{

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<PrivateChannel[]> responseEntity) {

 privateChannelConversationList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.privateConversationList);

            privateConversationAdapter = new PrivateConversationAdapter(conversationActivity, privateMapList);

            privateChannelConversationList.setAdapter(privateConversationAdapter);
// On click adapter excluded
}


    public class getConversationsForLoggedInUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]>> {

   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<RestGroupAccount[]> responseEntity) {
            super.onPostExecute(responseEntity);
groupAccountConversationList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversationList);

            groupConversationAdapter = new GroupConversationAdapter(conversationActivity, groupAccountMapList);

            groupAccountConversationList.setAdapter(groupConversationAdapter);

// On click adpater excluded
}
}
```

I hope this much information is sufficient, if anything else is required, let me know. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

This is how it looks : screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I have posted all code in this one pastebin if anyone is interested to check out the whole code : http://pastebin.com/huRMFAHa   . THank you.. :-)

Comment: Why do you use a drawerlayout? And why do you have Relativelayouts as wrappers within it? You should elaborate on those choices in your question.

Comment: @wvdz : Drawer layout is to show the navigation drawer. Not related to this problem. Relative layout, I don't know, I guess I found some stuff that way when I started this project, not much idea about Android. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They display on top of eachother because you put them both in a separate RelativeLayout that have the same positioning properties (none).

One fix would be to put both listViews in a LinearLayout instead. You can provide this LinearLayout with an orientation attribute vertical or horizontal, depending on how you want to display them, then use the `layout_weight` attribute to determine what portion of the screen each listviews occupies.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: `fill_parent` is legacy. Use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Do you have any idea how can I add a divider between the two lists, so that the user knows that this is a different list? Thank you.

Comment: I can think of three solutions for this. You could give the LinearLayout a background color, and apply top and bottom margin to the listviews. You could also define a border resource and put a border around each listview as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9238046/2947592. A third solution would be to put another View object in between the lists.

Comment: Can you please check this question about adding objects to UI : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332040/android-object-cannot-be-added-to-an-existing-list-as-its-not-original-thread    . Thanks a lot.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is because height of your both List Views is fill_parent. Try using wrap content or in your case i don't know how exactly do you want both List views to be displayed but I would suggest you use linear layout with orientation that you want and assign weights.

The layouts stack on each other in RelativeLayout as long as the cover the whole screen width and height.

Also fill_parent attribute value is deprecated now it is better to use match_parent.