# Android : Object cannot be added to an existing List as its not original thread

Tags: android, thread-safety, chat

I am working on an Android project in which I am working on chat functionality. In this, whenever a new message is received, I have to touch(literally) the screen, then only the new message can be seen. Also, for the first time, I get the below mentioned error. How can I add the object to already existing list. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

I get the latest message in `ChatListener`, which then is forwarded to a method which willtry to add it to the adapter.

Entire stacktrace :

```
03-31 14:30:15.578 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err: Handhskare complete[HttpClient@260236492-4456] INFO org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSession - Exception while invoking listener mycompany.app.Activity.ChatMessagesActivity$ChatListener@9b922a9
03-31 14:30:15.578 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:907)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.requestLayout(DrawerLayout.java:979)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
03-31 14:30:15.582 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1975)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:833)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6179)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at mycompany.app.Activity.ChatMessagesActivity.recieveUpdatedMessage(ChatMessagesActivity.java:265)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at mycompany.app.Activity.ChatMessagesActivity$ChatListener.onMessage(ChatMessagesActivity.java:473)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession$AbstractSessionChannel.notifyOnMessage(AbstractClientSession.java:501)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession$AbstractSessionChannel.notifyMessageListeners(AbstractClientSession.java:491)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.notifyListeners(AbstractClientSession.java:248)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.notifyListeners(BayeuxClient.java:1001)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.receive(AbstractClientSession.java:241)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.processMessage(BayeuxClient.java:787)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$PublishTransportListener.processMessage(BayeuxClient.java:1193)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$ConnectTransportListener.processMessage(BayeuxClient.java:1260)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$PublishTransportListener.onMessages(BayeuxClient.java:1185)
03-31 14:30:15.583 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport$2.onComplete(LongPollingTransport.java:254)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:185)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:446)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:393)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:265)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1430)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1272)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:156)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:117)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:69)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:89)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:108)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
03-31 14:30:15.584 21164-21484/mycompany.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Code :

```
public class ChatMessagesActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {


  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_messages);

 sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);

        typeMessageField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageTextField);
        typeMessageField.setHint("Type message here...");

  sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 Map<String, Object> outputData = new HashMap<>();
                    outputData.put("text", typeMessageField.getText().toString());
                    outputData.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outputData.put("type", false);
                    outputData.put("name",StaticRestTemplate.firstName);
                    consoleChatClient.bayeuxClient.getChannel("/service/person/" + String.valueOf(conversationId)).publish(outputData);
}


    public void recieveUpdatedMessage(String channelName, Map<String, Object> input) {

HashMap<String, String> insertMap = new HashMap<>();
                insertMap.put(chatText, ((Map) input.get("data")).get("text").toString());
                insertMap.put(firstName, ((Map) input.get("data")).get("firstname").toString());
 chatMessagesAdapter.add(insertMap);
                chatMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                chatList.scrollTo(0, chatList.getHeight());
}

 public class getGroupChatsForUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponseEntity<RestChatMessages[]>> {

        ChatMessagesActivity chatMessagesActivity = null;

        getGroupChatsForUser(ChatMessagesActivity chatMessagesActivity) {
            this.chatMessagesActivity = chatMessagesActivity;
        }

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<RestChatMessages[]> responseEntity) {
            super.onPostExecute(responseEntity);
 chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatList);

            chatMessagesAdapter = new ChatMessagesAdapter(chatMessagesActivity, chatMessagesHashMapList);


            chatList.setAdapter(chatMessagesAdapter);

            chatList.scrollTo(0, chatList.getHeight()); 
      }
   }

 public class ChatListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message).getJSONObject("data");
                String result = jsonObject.getString("type");

                if (result.equals("false")) {
                    recieveUpdatedMessage(channel.toString(), message);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the complete code in Pastebin for viewing : http://pastebin.com/PaRhtDJN

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier if you would paste all stacktrace, but I am assuming that you are changing views not from main thread.

Use this to when calling methods that are doing something with views:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        methodThatIsDoingViewStuff();
    }
});
```

Comment: Already made that change, without any effect. It actually makes the old chat messages also invisible.

Comment: please copy paste all stack trace

Comment: With the runOnUIThread, there is no error. I will remove, it and run again, then paste the log. Gimme 2 minutes.

Comment: Edited the main post to include the entire stacktrace. Kindly check it out. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Removing  chatList.scrollTo(0, chatList.getHeight()); solved the problem.. :-)